# Installing Open GApps on an Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-play-services

Using various emulators available through the AVD manager included with Android Studio, I've been attempting to install Open GApps without any luck. Generally, the procedure I've been taking is to download the appropriate package from Open GApps, push to the device with adb, then run the following command:

```
sh META-INF/com/google/android/update-binary 3 1 open_gapps-x86–6.0-mini-20170328.zip
```

or similar, as per this guide: [Installing Google Apps on VS Emulator for Android](https://medium.com/@yjwong/installing-google-apps-on-vs-emulator-for-android-6abe9c7167f4)

The installation script seems to finish running successfully, but on reboot, the device never gets past the boot screen.

My reason for trying to do this is because I need Google Play services on an emulator that *isn't* one of the two emulators that officially support it (Nexus 5/Nexus 5x I believe) because I need to use an emulator that supports Google Play *and* hardware GPU, which those two do not.

My exact steps:

1. Create a new AVD through the AVD manager included with Android Studio 3.1.2
2. I've tried multiple device types, for the sake of example I choose Pixel 2
3. My system image is Nougat, API 25, 7.1.1
4. In the advanced settings I choose hardware graphics, and increase the default storage size.
5. Once it's created, I launch the AVD and use Chrome to download the Open GApps app from [here](http://opengapps.org/app/).
6. This app automatically downloads the proper .zip package by detecting the device it's on.

At this point I follow the instructions described in the link above to completion.